# Identifying unique Pandas DataFrame groups and adding a new column / index accordingly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, unique

I've a Pandas DataFrame which contains a list of "solutions" explaining which materials should be added and removed to apply those solutions. Unfortunately, some solutions hold the same materials which should go in and out. Therefore I'd like to figure out which solutions are basically identical (except for the value in column "Solution") and add a new column to make that clear.

My dataset looks like this:

| Solution | IN_amount | in_matnr | in_mat | OUT_amount | out_matnr | out_mat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | 80000000 | QQQ |  |  |  |
| 3 | 1 | 22222222 | BBB |  |  |  |
| 3 | 1 | 33333333 | CCC |  |  |  |
| 3 | 2 | 44444444 | DDD |  |  |  |
| 3 | 3 | 55555555 | EEE |  |  |  |
| 3 |  |  |  | 1 | 18000000 | ZZZ |
| 1 | 1 | 22222222 | BBB |  |  |  |
| 1 | 1 | 11000000 | SSS |  |  |  |
| 1 | 2 | 40000000 | MMM |  |  |  |
| 1 | 2 | 12000000 | TTT |  |  |  |
| 2 | 1 | 80000000 | QQQ |  |  |  |
| 2 | 1 | 22222222 | BBB |  |  |  |
| 2 | 1 | 33333333 | CCC |  |  |  |
| 2 | 2 | 44444444 | DDD |  |  |  |
| 2 | 3 | 55555555 | EEE |  |  |  |
| 2 |  |  |  | 1 | 18000000 | ZZZ |

[...]

Here, the solutions 3 and 2 can be seen as identical solutions (the same materials are going in and out). I'd like to add a new column to mark those groups which contain the identical materials. Simplified:

| Solution | ... | Solution_unique |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | ... | 1 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 1 | ... | 2 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 2 | ... | 1 |
| ... | ... | ... |

This is what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{"Solution": 3, "IN_amount": 1, "in_matnr": 80000000, "in_mat": "QQQ"},
        {"Solution": 3, "IN_amount": 1, "in_matnr": 22222222, "in_mat": "BBB"},
        {"Solution": 3, "IN_amount": 1, "in_matnr": 33333333, "in_mat": "CCC"},
        {"Solution": 3, "IN_amount": 2, "in_matnr": 44444444, "in_mat": "DDD"},
        {"Solution": 3, "IN_amount": 3, "in_matnr": 55555555, "in_mat": "EEE"},
        {"Solution": 3, "OUT_amount": 1, "out_matnr": 18000000, "out_mat": "ZZZ"},
        {"Solution": 1, "IN_amount": 1, "in_matnr": 22222222, "in_mat": "BBB"},
        {"Solution": 1, "IN_amount": 1, "in_matnr": 11000000, "in_mat": "SSS"},
        {"Solution": 1, "IN_amount": 2, "in_matnr": 40000000, "in_mat": "MMM"},
        {"Solution": 1, "IN_amount": 2, "in_matnr": 12000000, "in_mat": "TTT"},
        {"Solution": 2, "IN_amount": 1, "in_matnr": 80000000, "in_mat": "QQQ"},
        {"Solution": 2, "IN_amount": 1, "in_matnr": 22222222, "in_mat": "BBB"},
        {"Solution": 2, "IN_amount": 1, "in_matnr": 33333333, "in_mat": "CCC"},
        {"Solution": 2, "IN_amount": 2, "in_matnr": 44444444, "in_mat": "DDD"},
        {"Solution": 2, "IN_amount": 3, "in_matnr": 55555555, "in_mat": "EEE"},
        {"Solution": 2, "OUT_amount": 1, "out_matnr": 18000000, "out_mat": "ZZZ"},
        {"Solution": 5, "IN_amount": 1, "in_matnr": 22222222, "in_mat": "BBB"},
        {"Solution": 5, "IN_amount": 2, "in_matnr": 90000000, "in_mat": "RRR"},
        {"Solution": 5, "OUT_amount": 1, "out_matnr": 17000000, "out_mat": "YYY"},
        {"Solution": 4, "IN_amount": 1, "in_matnr": 22222222, "in_mat": "BBB"},
        {"Solution": 4, "IN_amount": 1, "in_matnr": 11000000, "in_mat": "SSS"},
        {"Solution": 4, "IN_amount": 2, "in_matnr": 40000000, "in_mat": "MMM"},
        {"Solution": 4, "IN_amount": 2, "in_matnr": 12000000, "in_mat": "TTT"},
        {"Solution": 6, "IN_amount": 1, "in_matnr": 22222222, "in_mat": "BBB"},
        {"Solution": 6, "IN_amount": 1, "in_matnr": 13000000, "in_mat": "UUU"},
        {"Solution": 6, "IN_amount": 2, "in_matnr": 40000000, "in_mat": "MMM"},
        {"Solution": 6, "IN_amount": 2, "in_matnr": 12000000, "in_mat": "TTT"},
        {"Solution": 7, "IN_amount": 1, "in_matnr": 22222222, "in_mat": "BBB"},
        {"Solution": 7, "IN_amount": 1, "in_matnr": 13000000, "in_mat": "UUU"},
        {"Solution": 7, "IN_amount": 2, "in_matnr": 40000000, "in_mat": "MMM"},
        {"Solution": 7, "IN_amount": 2, "in_matnr": 12000000, "in_mat": "TTT"}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df = df.groupby("Solution")
```

Which gives me something like

```
  Solution  IN_amount    in_matnr in_mat  OUT_amount   out_matnr out_mat
0          3        1.0  80000000.0    QQQ         NaN         NaN     NaN
1          3        1.0  22222222.0    BBB         NaN         NaN     NaN
2          3        1.0  33333333.0    CCC         NaN         NaN     NaN
3          3        2.0  44444444.0    DDD         NaN         NaN     NaN
4          3        3.0  55555555.0    EEE         NaN         NaN     NaN
5          3        NaN         NaN    NaN         1.0  18000000.0     ZZZ
6          1        1.0  22222222.0    BBB         NaN         NaN     NaN
7          1        1.0  11000000.0    SSS         NaN         NaN     NaN
8          1        2.0  40000000.0    MMM         NaN         NaN     NaN
9          1        2.0  12000000.0    TTT         NaN         NaN     NaN
[...]
```

Now I'm stuck at counting unique groups and adding a kind of marker inside a new column (Solution_unique).

Thank you in advance, I'm looking forward to your assistance!
Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would extract the subdataframes, compute their hashes with [`pandas.util.hash_pandas_object`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.util.hash_pandas_object.html)/[`hash`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hash) and use this information to identify the identical groups:

```
hashes = pd.Series({k: hash(tuple(pd.util.hash_pandas_object(g, index=False)))
                    for k, g in df.sort_values(by=list(df.columns.difference(['Solution'])))
                                  .drop(columns='Solution').groupby(df['Solution'], sort=False)}
                  )

df['Solution_unique'] = df['Solution'].map(dict(zip(hashes.index, pd.factorize(hashes)[0]+1)))
```

Output:

```
    Solution  IN_amount    in_matnr in_mat  OUT_amount   out_matnr out_mat  Solution_unique
0          3        1.0  80000000.0    QQQ         NaN         NaN     NaN                1
1          3        1.0  22222222.0    BBB         NaN         NaN     NaN                1
2          3        1.0  33333333.0    CCC         NaN         NaN     NaN                1
3          3        2.0  44444444.0    DDD         NaN         NaN     NaN                1
4          3        3.0  55555555.0    EEE         NaN         NaN     NaN                1
5          3        NaN         NaN    NaN         1.0  18000000.0     ZZZ                1
6          1        1.0  22222222.0    BBB         NaN         NaN     NaN                2
7          1        1.0  11000000.0    SSS         NaN         NaN     NaN                2
8          1        2.0  40000000.0    MMM         NaN         NaN     NaN                2
9          1        2.0  12000000.0    TTT         NaN         NaN     NaN                2
10         2        1.0  80000000.0    QQQ         NaN         NaN     NaN                1
11         2        1.0  22222222.0    BBB         NaN         NaN     NaN                1
12         2        1.0  33333333.0    CCC         NaN         NaN     NaN                1
13         2        2.0  44444444.0    DDD         NaN         NaN     NaN                1
14         2        3.0  55555555.0    EEE         NaN         NaN     NaN                1
15         2        NaN         NaN    NaN         1.0  18000000.0     ZZZ                1
16         5        1.0  22222222.0    BBB         NaN         NaN     NaN                3
17         5        2.0  90000000.0    RRR         NaN         NaN     NaN                3
18         5        NaN         NaN    NaN         1.0  17000000.0     YYY                3
19         4        1.0  22222222.0    BBB         NaN         NaN     NaN                2
20         4        1.0  11000000.0    SSS         NaN         NaN     NaN                2
21         4        2.0  40000000.0    MMM         NaN         NaN     NaN                2
22         4        2.0  12000000.0    TTT         NaN         NaN     NaN                2
23         6        1.0  22222222.0    BBB         NaN         NaN     NaN                4
24         6        1.0  13000000.0    UUU         NaN         NaN     NaN                4
25         6        2.0  40000000.0    MMM         NaN         NaN     NaN                4
26         6        2.0  12000000.0    TTT         NaN         NaN     NaN                4
27         7        1.0  22222222.0    BBB         NaN         NaN     NaN                4
28         7        1.0  13000000.0    UUU         NaN         NaN     NaN                4
29         7        2.0  40000000.0    MMM         NaN         NaN     NaN                4
30         7        2.0  12000000.0    TTT         NaN         NaN     NaN                4
```

Intermediates:

```
hashes

3    2408158917466943276
1   -9038486839634175931
2    2408158917466943276
5    2000192472388552548
4   -9038486839634175931
6    1944556807772715310
7    1944556807772715310
dtype: int64


dict(zip(hashes.index, pd.factorize(hashes)[0]+1))

{3: 1, 1: 2, 2: 1, 5: 3, 4: 2, 6: 4, 7: 4}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I've testet your proposal. That's close to what I'm looking for.

Looking at the hashes, the solutions 3,2 / 1,4,6,7 are identical, 5 is unique. Something is wrong here. From my point of view, the solutions 3,2 / 1,4 and 6,7 are identical, 5 is unique. The difference between the solutions 1,4 / 6,7 are the materials  11000000.0 SSS instead of 13000000.0 UUU.

I think only the values in IN_amount are taken into account to calculate the hash value. How can I calculate the hash value for the combination of IN_amount, in_matnr, in_mat, OUT_amount, out_matnr and out_mat?

Comment: @Max yes, for some reason I forgot to remove a slice, if was only using one column. See update, it's now using all columns (except Solution) ;)

Comment: I should've checked earlier if you've seen my comment already. Works great, thank you very much!

If certain columns should be chosen, it works like this: 
```
hashes = pd.Series({k: hash(tuple(pd.util.hash_pandas_object(g[['IN_amount', 'in_matnr']], index=False)))
                   for k, g in df.sort_values(by=list(df.columns.difference(['Solution'])))
                                  .drop(columns='Solution').groupby(df['Solution'], sort=False)}
                  )
```

Comment: Exactly, just slice what you need ;)

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly, here is a possible solution:

```
for n, (idx, grp) in enumerate(df.groupby(['IN_amount', 'in_matnr'])):
    if len(grp) == 1:
        continue
    df.loc[grp.index, 'Solution_unique'] = n
```

This will go through all the groups that have the same `IN_amount` and `in_matnr` and assign a unique number (`n`) to that group. You can change the column names on the list that is passed to groupby to change which columns you want to check to see if they are identical. I also added `len(grp) == 1` so it doesn't give a unique solution to solutions that only occur once, but you can remove it.

If your dataset is really large, this function can get really slow. In that case, I would consider converting the dataframe to numpy and using the `numpy.unique` function instead.

Comment: Thank you very much! I've testet your proposal. From my understanding you're assigning  identical numbers to rows containing the same data (considering the columns IN_amount and in_matnr).

Unfortunately, I'm trying to compare all rows which belong to a given solution. In my example above, I've 7 solutions. But only 4 of these "sets" are unique.

After identifying these unique solutions, I can tell you that the machine (for example) where solution 3 would work, solution 2 would work too because they hold identical materials.

Comment: `for n, (idx, grp) in enumerate(df.groupby(['IN_amount', 'in_matnr'])):
    df.loc[grp.index, 'Solution_unique'] = n`



results in

```
    Solution IN_amount in_matnr in_mat OUT_amount out_matnr out_mat Solution_unique
0 3 1.0 80000000.0 QQQ NaN NaN NaN 4.0
1 3 1.0 22222222.0 BBB NaN NaN NaN 2.0
2 3 1.0 33333333.0 CCC NaN NaN NaN 3.0
[...]
6 1 1.0 22222222.0 BBB NaN NaN NaN 2.0
7 1 1.0 11000000.0 SSS NaN NaN NaN 0.0
8 1 2.0 40000000.0 MMM NaN NaN NaN 6.0
9 1 2.0 12000000.0 TTT NaN NaN NaN 5.0
10 2 1.0 80000000.0 QQQ NaN NaN NaN 4.0
```

I don't get the formatting...